# INNER JOIN causing NULL RECORD SET

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. Below is my SQL statement. `timetabledistribution` is my transaction table. This is working fine. BUT this is returning `NULL` record when there is a record with `teacherId = NULL` in `timetabledistribution` table.
I believe this is because there is a `INNER JOIN teacher_profiles c ON a.teacherId = c.teacherId`  in the SQL statement. 
Is there any possibility to avoid or ignore this JOIN if teacherId = NULL for those kind of records? Or any other better way …

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(a.periodWeekDayId, '.', a.periodId) as Id, 
    a.periodId, 
    a.periodWeekDayId, 
    a.subjectId, 
    b.subjectShortName, 
    a.teacherId, 
    CONCAT(c.teacherFirstName , ' ', COALESCE(c.teacherMiddleName, ''), ' ', c.teacherLastName ) as teacherName , 
    e.classStd, 
    f.sectionName, 
    g.templateName, 
    h.periodLabel, 
    h.periodStartTime, 
    h.periodEndTime, 
    i.periodWeekDayName, 
    a.timeTableClassSectionId 
FROM timetabledistribution a 
    INNER JOIN subject_master b ON a.subjectId = b.subjectId 
    INNER JOIN teacher_profiles c ON a.teacherId = c.teacherId 
    INNER JOIN TimeTableClassSection d ON a.TimeTableClassSectionId = d.TimeTableClassSectionId 
    INNER JOIN class_master e ON d.classId = e.classId 
    INNER JOIN section_master f ON d.sectionId = f.sectionId 
    INNER JOIN TimeTableTemplate    g ON d.timeTableTemplateId = g.timeTableTemplateId 
    INNER JOIN templatePeriodStructure  h ON a.periodId = h.periodId 
    INNER JOIN templateWeekDaysStructure    i ON a.periodWeekDayId = i.periodWeekDayId 
WHERE A.TimeTableClassSectionId='46'
```

I want rest of field should be return except teacher detail as teacherId is NULL for that particular record. 
But the query is ignoring entire record.

```
Id  periodId    periodWeekDayId …..
1   12      1
```

But Getting

```
Id  periodId    periodWeekDayId …..
NULL    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: I'm a little confused....

Have you tried making the JOIN to teacher profiles a LEFT OUTER
So change to........
LEFT OUTER JOIN teacher_profiles c ON a.teacherId = c.teacherId

Comment: make sense .. I think I missed that .. thanks for advise

Comment: @AntDC Put that into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad it helped......

Have you tried making the JOIN to teacher profiles a LEFT OUTER So change to........

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN teacher_profiles c ON a.teacherId = c.teacherId
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are driving this from timetabledistribution table surely you can simply append to the where condition....
So it becomes...

```
..
..
WHERE A.TimeTableClassSectionId='46'
AND A.teacherID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It still giving me NULL record SET. I want rest of field should be return except teacher detail as teacherId is NULL for that particular record.

Comment: add more description above if it helps